# Creating a responsive shape with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I'm attempting to create the following shape in Bootstrap so it's responsive. I've been able to get the entire container to transform, however I'm trying to make only the bottom have the slant. This will be a footer on the page so I'll end up having text placed along the left side of it.

This is the effect I'm trying to make:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
<footer class="footer container-fluid">
  <div class="skew">
      <div class="header-inner">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><h3>1</h3></li>
          <li><h3>2</h3></li>
          <li><h3>3</h3></li>
          <li><h3>4</h3></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</footer>

.footer {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.footer .skew:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform-property: bottom;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-2deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-2deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-2deg);
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
}

.footer .skew .header-inner {
  max-width: 850px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: $white;
}
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate me on this? *however I'm trying to make only the bottom have the slant*

Comment: @ManojKumar I added a screenshot at the top of the page

Comment: I'm trying to create the shape.

Comment: huffla, read my answer :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use an SVG behind your text? You could try something like this:

http://codepen.io/tinyglowstudio/pen/Mwdoxm

```
<svg style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:200px; left:0" viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,0 L10,0 L0,10 z" fill="#F00" />
</svg>
```

The preserveAspectRatio lets the image scale in whatever direction the box is. Right now, I'm taking the shape from the top left corner (M0,0 of our viewBox) to the top right (L10,0), to the bottom left (L0,10) and then back to the starting point (z). Change your coordinates as desired.